# Cassandra Nagios plugins

Tags: cassandra, jmx, nagios, datastax

I am trying to monitor cassandra using nagios casandra plugins by following this link. 
http://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/docs/Monitoring_Apache_Cassandra_Databases_with_Nagios_XI.pdf

I do not see core config manager as I am using Nagios 3.3.1. How do we configure casandra specific checks using Nagios Core 3.3.1. Can anyone who did it point me to a good resource please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can still use the plug in, you simply must set it up 'by hand'.  Have you read the NRPE and Nagios docs for the version you have?

Answer (score 2):

The Nagios Core version 3 manual can be found here: http://library.nagios.com/library/products/nagioscore/manuals/
Instead of performing steps 5 and 6 in the pdf you attached, you will have to add the server, the command, and the service check to the Nagios .cfg files manually.

1. Create the host object for the server using this page: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html#host
2. Create a command object for the new Cassandra check, using this: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html#command
3. Create the service object, the details are found here:  http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html#service

Remember that the items in 'red' on those pages are required in the object entries.